# How to use new elasticsearch typescript types

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch

I want to use new elastic search types as per this TypeScript support | Elasticsearch Node.js client [7.x] | Elastic 1 document but if I do

```
// try the new code completion when building a query!
const response = await client.search<Source>({
  index: 'test',
  body: {
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  }
})

// try the new code completion when traversing a response!
const results = response.body.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
// results type will be `Source[]`
console.log(results)
```

my results object itself coming as type I have provided and not coming as SearchResponse

Comment: According to the type information, `response.body` will be typed as whatever is provided as the first type parameter to `Client.search`. You set that to `Source`, so you should simply get a `Source`, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use elasticsearch node module version >=7.13 to use new type suport